# How to disassemble the ZF S6-53 transmission (BMW Jaguar Land Rover etc)

Tags: transmission

I need to remove the front housing of this transmission so I can machine the bell housing flange off and weld a new one on.

ZF are very reluctantly give out service or workshop manuals.

I have removed all of the detents and all the fixing pins that screw through the side, the circlip on the input shaft and the bolt that goes through the bearing behind the cover under the input shaft.

The front housing moves around 3-5mm away from the rear housing but doesn’t go any further, I’ve tried hitting the lower shaft back through the bearing but it still will not budge.

Does anyone know how to remove the front housing / bell housing is removed from this gearbox?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered that the back cover may possibly come off first? leaving all the internals with the front housing, and then dismantled from there? Don't know, but something to consider...

Comment: Yeah I have, that's the next thing to try but I just wanting to see if someone had a definitive answer before I go to the effort of re configuring the stand and disassembling the rear section.

Comment: Have you looked at manuals like this (have not dug more though) : https://workshop-manuals.com/landrover/lr3/308-03_manual_transmission_transaxle-_2.7l_diesel/specifications/

Comment: Yeah I have and Land Rover don't approve transmission repair, they just replace with new and send the core back to ZF

Comment: Having stripped and rebuilt earlier L/R boxes including early R/R ones (because I shoved 160bhp through instead of 50 or 60...) I can understand that...

Comment: What does it look like inside the bell housing?

Comment: i'm from france and i'm loking wordwide on the net since 2 days to find a solution for dissemble this gearbox, the mine is a x5 e53 and the gearbox is gs6x53dz i m trying about 2 days and i ve even broken a part of back cover and i was very desperete but now i have some , i wanted to ask you if you had difficulty to assembly it after and if you took other photos while you repairing. i woud very glad if you could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had another go today with success.

The bell housing does indeed come off from the front. The input shaft and lay shaft are very tight in the bearings that are pressed into the bell housing. (And I mean very tight)

I made a very crude bearing press out of a off cut of c section and some M20 threaded bar. I put pressure on the layshaft and then took it in turns to hit the threaded bar (and in turn the layshaft) and the input shaft with a very large copper hammer.

[image]

[image]